# Atomからショートカットキーで拡張子に紐付いたアプリの起動

Tags: atom-editor, サクラエディタ

現在Windowsでサクラエディタを用いていますが、Atomへの移行を検討しています。
その中で個人的に外せないものがサクラエディタではCtrl+BでできたIDEの起動です。
（拡張子にIDEが紐付いており普段はアイコンをダブルクリックで、サクラエディタからはCtrl+Bで起動するようになっています。）

http://sakura-editor.sourceforge.net/htmlhelp/HLP000121.html
の機能です。

これをAtomで実現させる設定もしくはパッケージ等ありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。
（ターミナルやコマンドプロンプトの起動ではありません。）

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

拡張子に紐づけられた実行ファイルでファイルを開くためには、`cmd.exe` の組み込みコマンド [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) が実行できればよいので、[atom-shell-commands](https://atom.io/packages/atom-shell-commands) パッケージ / [dqs-shell-commands](https://atom.io/packages/dqs-shell-commands) パッケージや [process-palette](https://atom.io/packages/process-palette) パッケージなど、外部コマンドの実行ができるパッケージを活用すれば実現できます。

#### process-palette の場合のコンフィグ例

process-palette であれば、以下のようにコンフィグすると <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> で拡張子に紐づけられた実行ファイルを使ってファイルが開くようになります。ポイントは `command` が `cmd.exe /C start {fileAbsPath}` になっていることと、スクリーンショットには写っていませんが、`success` 時も通知しない設定にしてあることです。

[image: run-ide コマンドの設定例です。下の process-palette.json 相当の設定がしてある部分のスクショです。]

`process-palette.json` の一部

```
    {
      "namespace": "process-palette",
      "action": "run-ide",
      "command": "cmd.exe /C start {fileAbsPath}",
      "arguments": [],
      "cwd": null,
      "inputDialogs": [],
      "env": {},
      "keystroke": "ctrl-shift-b",
      "stream": false,
      "outputTarget": "panel",
      "outputBufferSize": 80000,
      "maxCompleted": 3,
      "autoShowOutput": false,
      "autoHideOutput": false,
      "scrollLockEnabled": false,
      "singular": false,
      "promptToSave": true,
      "saveOption": "none",
      "patterns": [
        "default"
      ],
      "successOutput": "{stdout}",
      "errorOutput": "{stdout}\n{stderr}",
      "fatalOutput": "Failed to execute : {fullCommand}\n{stdout}\n{stderr}",
      "startMessage": null,
      "successMessage": "Executed : {fullCommand}",
      "errorMessage": "Executed : {fullCommand}\nReturned with code {exitStatus}\n{stderr}",
      "fatalMessage": "Failed to execute : {fullCommand}\n{stdout}\n{stderr}",
      "menus": [],
      "startScript": null,
      "successScript": null,
      "errorScript": null,
      "scriptOnStart": false,
      "scriptOnSuccess": false,
      "scriptOnError": false,
      "notifyOnStart": false,
      "notifyOnSuccess": false,
      "notifyOnError": true,
      "input": null
    }
```

#### dqs-shell-commands の場合のコンフィグ例

dqs-shell-commands であれば、以下のようにコンフィグすると <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> で同様の動作ができます。

`global-shell-commands.cson` の例

```
commands: [
  {
    name: "runide"
    command: "cmd"
    arguments: [
      "/C"
      "start"
      "{FileName}"
    ]
    options:
      cwd: "{FileDir}"
      keymap: "ctrl-shift-b"
  }
]
```

Comment: atom-shell-commandsパッケージの例でいうと"{FileNameNoExt}"や"{FileDir}"のあたりをideのexeファイルのパスに変える感じでしょうか？
お手すきの際にアドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Comment: @user87562 atom-shell-commands は 2017 年 3 月から[新しいメンテナを探している](https://github.com/skywind3000/atom-shell-commands/issues/20)ようでしたので、代わりに atom-shell-commands を受け継いだ dqs-shell-commands と、別系統のパッケージである process-palette についてコンフィグ例を書いてみました。ご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事process-paletteで望んでいた動作ができました。まるまるスクショの通りでスムーズに行きました。（実行後にatomの下に邪魔なのが出てくるのは気になりましたが）

Comment: 実行後に邪魔なのが出てくるのは、設定で消すことができます。notifyOnSuccess のチェックを外す (false にする) のをお試しください。GUI での設定画面の場合、下の方にチェックボックスがあります。他にもコンフィグできるようになっているので、自分好みに改造して使うのが良いと思います。

Comment: ご存知かとは思いますが key の設定を変えればどのキーマップに割り当てるかも変更可能です。Atom の場合 keybindings から現在のキーコンフィグ一覧を見ることができるので、空いてるキーを探すなり既存のキーを上書きするなり自分で選ぶことができます。