# Vimからショートカットキーで拡張子に紐付いたアプリの起動

Tags: vim

[Atomからショートカットキーで拡張子に紐付いたアプリの起動](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41160/atom%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%AB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E5%AD%90%E3%81%AB%E7%B4%90%E4%BB%98%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95)

以前質問させていただいたこの質問ですが、AtomだけでなくVimも使うことになりVimではどうしようか悩み検索中です。
（ちなみに質問内容は　拡張子にIDEが紐付いており普段はアイコンをダブルクリックで、サクラエディタからはCtrl+Bで起動するようになっています。これをvimでも実現させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

こちらのページのプラグインを用いてもよいのですが、
http://toritori0318.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20110527/1306521357
わざわざNerdtreeを使うことなく.vimrcの記述だけで行けるならそちらで行きたいと考えています。（ファイルを選択する手間があるため）また、プラグインだとしてもファイルを選ぶことなく現在編集中のファイルをショートカットキーで外部起動させられたらと考えています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

元質問を参考にすると、以下のようにvimrcに追記すれば良いと思います。
ノーマルモードでCtrl-bを押すと実行されます。
詳しくは`:help !`してください。なお、`%`は現在編集中のファイル名に置換されます。

```
nnoremap <C-b> :!cmd /C start %
```